# Drush and user permissions

Tags: drush, files

I see that my user is a member of the apache group. I added and confirmed via the following

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G apache `whoami`  # add my user to apache group
$ sudo chmod -R g+w .                 # permit group members to write 
$ groups `whoami`                     # confirm I'm in the apache group
```

However, when I attempt to run a drush update core or even drush cron

```
$ drush cc all

unlink(sites/default/files/css/css_71ba7c25a8d3c47c68a8e05608ae525c.css):[warning]
Permission denied file.inc:482
```

[image]

And the CSS cache in this situation looks like

```
$ ll
total 1536
drwxrwxr-x.  2 apache apache  12288 Nov 26 10:12 .
drwxrwxr-x. 11 apache apache   4096 Nov 24 20:35 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 apache apache 162269 Nov 26 10:06 css_00d5f4d7c5c92cd4f.css
-rw-rw-r--   1 apache apache 158090 Nov 26 10:02 css_0605989692a2119d305.css
-rw-rw-r--   1 apache apache 162269 Nov 26 10:02 css_0779dcac71ee9aa8e02d9e.css
```

[image]

I would assume that my user account, which has sudo access, should be a group member of apache (or www-data) and that the file tree should permit group write access. Any help or points in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: run `newgrp apache` without sudo and try again

Comment: Did you log out and then back in again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the other answer is informative, I now use the proper user permission as described in

***Securing file permissions and ownership***

- https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Which opens with

> The server file system should be configured so that the web server
>   (e.g. Apache) does not have permission to edit or write the files
>   which it then executes. That is, all of your files should be 'read
>   only' for the Apache process, and owned with write permissions by a
>   separate user.

Comment: The article that you link to does not mention Drush. Could you, please, clarify which user you are using to run Drush commands and how is that user set up.

Comment: Interesting! I think you should also mention the 2 pargs that follow the one you already quoted ...

Comment: In Drupal files folder needs to be writable by the webserver, and in development you will probably need that for features folder too.

Comment: This article also says:

"...For the "files" directory in the sites/default directory and any other site directories in a multi-site installation, the permissions are slightly different because the www-data user must have write permission to the directory:..."

`[root@localhost]cd /path_to_drupal_installation/sites
[root@localhost]find . -type d -name files -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;`

Answer (score 15):

Arguably, a much more straightforward approach is to not muck with your user's group assignments at all and instead run drush as the web server user (ie: apache, www-data).

**Use sudo:**

```
sudo -u apache drush
```

or on debian/ubuntu:

```
sudo -u www-data drush
```

**Create a command alias:**

Then, to ensure that you always run drush like that, add an alias:

```
echo "alias drush='sudo -u apache drush'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

or on debian/ubuntu:

```
echo "alias drush='sudo -u www-data drush'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

Now when running any drush command, you'll be prompted for your password by sudo, and the command will run as the web server user. No more permissions problem reading and writing files.

Comment: When I run "sudo -u www-data drush" it complains that the drush-backups directory is not writable.

Comment: @Magmatic just change permissions to that folder, make it writeable for www-data, check who is the owner.

Comment: I have a related issue here where I'm trying to run drush commands against the production server via remote site aliases. Do you have any insight as to how to accomplish this? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/312977/how-to-use-drush-remote-site-aliases-with-web-service-or-other-account

Answer (score 1):

When I ran drush as `www-data` drush was no longer available as my [$PATH had changed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245772/why-running-command-as-sudo-returns-command-not-found).

As a workaround you can enter the whole path to drush.

E.g.

```
sudo -u www-data /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin/drush status
```

To get the path of your drush you can run:

```
which drush
```

Which means you can also just run:

```
sudo -u www-data `which drush` status
```

which removes the need to hard code the path in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Inside files folder

```
chown -R youruser:www-data .
find . -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
find . -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o= '{}' \;
```

See: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924#linux-servers